# PyTorch ConvNet randomly learns a single label and gets stuck

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am trying to classify two types of images (i.e. 2 labels). I have over 30k images for my training dataset, and have built the CNN that's described below.

Here's the weird part - I've trained this network over 20 times, and I get 2 completely different behaviours - 

1. **The network will in fact "learn"**, loss decreases and after about 10 epochs I'll correctly classify about 80% of my test dataset.

2. After seeing ~1k pictures (not even a single epoch), **the network will "decide" to always classify the images as only one of the labels!** Loss get's stuck and nothing happens

The strange part - it's the exact same piece of code! nothing changes.
I tried debugging for so many hours and got to a point where I don't have a clue what's going on. 

 
The only thing that I noticed is when the network fails to learn, then the initial output of the network (w/o performing even one backprop iteration) is something like -

```
model = MyNetwork()
images, labels  = iter(train_dataset_loader).next()
fw_pass_output = model(images)
print(fw_pass_output[:5])
---
tensor([[9.4696e-09, 1.0000e+00],
        [2.8105e-08, 1.0000e+00],
        [7.4285e-09, 1.0000e+00],
        [4.3701e-09, 1.0000e+00],
        [4.4942e-08, 1.0000e+00]], grad_fn=<SliceBackward>)
```

And on the other hand when the network does succeed in learning, it'll look like this -

```
tensor([[0.4982, 0.5018],
        [0.4353, 0.5647],
        [0.3051, 0.6949],
        [0.4823, 0.5177],
        [0.4342, 0.5658]], grad_fn=<SliceBackward>)
```

So as you can see - when the network manages to learn, seems like the initial weight initialisation is allowing more balanced results, while on another occasion it'll just arbitrarily assign everything to one of the classes, and from there it never manages to learn anything.

I tried swapping between Adam/SGD, lot's of different learning rates, different weight decay values, nothing helped...

What am I missing? What's causing this behaviour? Is it a bug in my code, or a concept that I'm missing?

```
class MyNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyNetwork, self).__init__()

        self.conv1_layer = nn.Conv2d(3, 32, 5) 
        self.conv2_layer = nn.Conv2d(32, 16, 3) 
        self.conv3_layer = nn.Conv2d(16, 8, 2) 

        self.layer_size_after_convs = 8 * 5 * 5 
        TOTAL_NUM_OF_CLASSES = 2
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(self.layer_size_after_convs, TOTAL_NUM_OF_CLASSES)

    def forward(self, x):
        """
        Perform a forward pass on the network
        """
        x = F.relu(self.conv1_layer(x))
        x = F.max_pool2d(x, (3, 3))

        x = F.relu(self.conv2_layer(x))
        x = F.max_pool2d(x, (2, 2))

        x = F.relu(self.conv3_layer(x))
        x = F.max_pool2d(x, (2, 2))
            x = x.view(-1, self.layer_size_after_convs)
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = F.softmax(x, dim=1)
        return x

model = MyNetwork()
loss_func = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.001, weight_decay=0.1)

total_steps = len(train_dataset_loader)

epochs = 100
for epoch_num in range(epochs):
    for i, (img_batch, labels) in enumerate(train_dataset_loader):
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        fw_pass_output = model(img_batch)
        loss_values = loss_func(fw_pass_output, labels)        
        loss_values.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        print ('Epoch [{}/{}], Step [{}/{}], Loss: {:.4f}'.format(epoch_num+1, epochs, i+1, total_steps, loss_values.item()))
```

Comment: This can happen when the optimizer gets stuck in a local minimum.  You can try a lower learning rate - that can sometimes help.

You may also want to look into adapting a pre-trained CNN to your problem.  See https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html for an example of what I mean.

Comment: But it also happens before the optimiser even had a chance to do something! There are certain network initialisations in which everything is classified as one label before I optimize anything! that's why I assume this is some kind of software bug on my behalf...

Comment: Try turning off weight decay for now. The value of 0.1 is _extremely_ large. It's more normal to have something like 1e-6 to 1e-4.

Comment: You are using [`nn.CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss), which applies log-softmax, but you also use a regular softmax before it. That might cause some stability issues. You should remove the `F.softmax(x, dim=1)` from the model and only apply it if you want to see the probabilities.